# Dot at end of menu element

Tags: wordpress, scroll, menu

I'm trying to make a Wordpress menu that scrolls to a specific place on a page when you click on a menu item. When the viewport is on that element of page there's a dot at the end of the menu item title and moves acordingly which part of the page is visible. E.g. When you click on "photo" on the menu it scrolls to the photo section and a dot slides to the end of the word "photo." Then when you click "contact" the dot slides from the end of the word "photo" to the end of the word "contact" and the page scrolls to the contact section. The dot should also slide when you scroll to a section manually. I've tried to use onScroll but failed. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is related to **scrollspy**. If i got you correct then, try this link:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_scrollspy&stacked=h

Comment: I have problem using this plugin in wordpress. I can't make the active link change it's css code using .active link state. This seams to do the trick: https://ayanize.com/snippets/how-to-highlight-current-menu-items-on-a-one-page-site-in-divi/ but I cant make a dot at the end to move from button to button (something like the dot move example in here: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/21/dot-navigation-styles/ )